# Overriding application.yml config properties with runtime.groovy properties in Grails 3

Tags: configuration, grails3

I'm having config issues in Grails 3 and want to hook into the config setup process, unless there's a better way

We have a plugin(jasypt) that requires config set in the `application.yml` or it throws errors(example below). We need to set the config values in `runtime.groovy`, but they don't override any values set in the `yml`

`application.yml`

```
jasypt:
  algorithm: "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
  providerName: "BC"
  password: "-"
  keyObtentionIterations: 10
```

`runtime.groovy`

```
jasypt {
    algorithm = ExternalSecureKeyConfig.getInstance().jasypt.algorithm
    providerName = ExternalSecureKeyConfig.getInstance().jasypt.providerName
    password = ExternalSecureKeyConfig.getInstance().jasypt.password
    keyObtentionIterations = ExternalSecureKeyConfig.getInstance().jasypt.keyObtentionIterations
}
```

Debugging during startup and runtime shows that none of the config gets overridden (password stays "-"). If I move config from the `yml` to `application.groovy` the runtime values get applied but I get the following error on startup

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: If "encryptorRegisteredName" is not specified, then "password" (and optionally "algorithm" and "keyObtentionIterations") must be specified
```

Currently I'm hoping I can manually set the jsypt config values or hook into the groovy config setup to ensure they override the prev set yml values. Having trouble figuring how to do this or if it's possible

`jasypt v 2.0.2 with Grails 3.3.10 (hibernate5, gorm 6.1)`

Answer (score 0):

### Solve

Overriding the application.yml config with values from a custom config file. Still find is strand the runtime.groovy doesn't override yml config values.

```
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
    }

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        URL jasyptConfigUrl = getClass().classLoader.getResource('jasypt.groovy')
        if (jasyptConfigUrl) {
            def jasyptConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(jasyptConfigUrl)
            environment.propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource('jasypt.groovy', jasyptConfig))
        }
    }
}
```